# Flexbox: centered element with space-around elements on either side

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to set up a menu consisting of seven `<li>` elements with various widths. I'd like my middle (4th in the source order) `<li>` element to always be horizontally centered as a sort of anchor, with the 1-3rd `<li>` elements occupying the space to the left of the centered `<li>` and the 5th-7th occupying the space to the right.

[image]

I've tried `space-around`, `space-between` on the parent flex container as well as `align-self: center` on the `<li>` element I'm trying to center, but so far no luck. Any help from someone knowledgeable in flexbox would be appreciated.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7kCc/26/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to modify your `nav` structure and start from 3 containers *left*, *center* and *right*. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g7kCc/28/)**

---

**HTML**

*left* and *right*  will hold a few links, *center* is a link.

```
<nav>
<span>
    <a href="#">aaa </a>
    <a href="#">aa </a>
    <a href="#">a </a>
    </span>
    <a href="#"> center </a>
    <span>
      <a href="#">bbbb </a>
      <a href="#">bbbbb </a>
      <a href="#">bbbbbb </a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

---

**CSS**

nav will take `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-between`, so will *left* and *right*.

```
nav, nav span {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-wrap:wrap;/* so they do not overlap each other if space too short */
}
```

To generate a gap at edges of *right* and *left* towards center, we just add a pseudo element *(or an empty element)*.

```
span:first-of-type:after,
span:last-of-type:before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;/* enough , no width needed , it will still generate a space between */
}
```

*left* and *right* can take a `flex` value **higher** than `1` , to avoid *center* to expand too much.

```
nav > span {
    flex:2; /* 2 is minimum but plenty enough here  */
}
```

lets draw our link boxes :

```
a {
    padding:0 0.25em;
    border:solid;
}
```

---

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g7kCc/28/)**

Comment: The trick is to set `flex:2;` on right and left block. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do this is to split the items into three different `ul` elements, and then use the `flex` property to set how large the three columns are.

The outside columns have three elements in them, so they get `flex:3`. The centered column only has one element, so it gets `flex:1`. That way, when you resize, flexbox will use 3 flex units for the larger columns, and 1 flex unit for the centered column. If you need to use a different number of items in any of the columns, just change the `flex` unit to reflect how many items are inside it.

Working fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7kCc/29/)

Comment: nav do not need ul to build a menu, but this is the method, no matter tag names you use :) , i made it shorter compare to you.

Comment: I know you don't need a `ul` in a `nav`. He didn't ask to have his semantics critiqued.

Comment: sorry, i did not mean mean